# Set an empty value to a textarea according to checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have a little problem with some jQuery code.

In my page I have the following layout :

```
[X] "Some text"   [textarea]
[X] "Some text 2" [textarea]
[X] "Some text 3" [textarea]
```

So basically, it's just some checkboxes and some textarea (which is a date-picker in fact), and the code is the following (generated in PHP) :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="pack_check" disabled="disabled" name="id_pack[]" value="0 />     
Some text
<input name="date-pack[]" id="date-pack[]" class="date-picker">
<input type="checkbox" class="pack_check" disabled="disabled" name="id_pack[]" value="1 />     
Some text 2
<input name="date-pack[]" id="date-pack[]" class="date-picker">
```

The thing is, I want that when the user uncheck a checkbox, the associated date (in the textarea input) get an empty value...

I achieved this by doing something like that :

```
$('input.pack_check').change(function () {
        $("input[name='date-pack[]']").val("");
});
```

But when I do this, ALL the textarea are being erased.

Any idea?

Comment: You shouldn't have the same `id` for different elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot redeclare an ID once you used it once in the document - if you do, you will see some very non-standard behaviour like the one you're experiencing

this is what I'd do:

```
$('input.pack_check').click(function() {
    if (!this.checked) {
        $(this).nextAll('input:first').val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, I have misread this question, check the updated version, it should work for you... also, use click() instead of change() event on checkboxes, since they only fire up change() event when you click elsewhere from the active checkbox in MSIE

Comment: also, you are missing a closing quote in your value attributes: <input type="checkbox" class="pack_check" disabled="disabled" name="id_pack[]" value="1 <-- here

Comment: I tried with your last edit, and it doesn't work. I also tried to alert() the value of the selector `alert($(this).nextAll('input:first').val(''));`, but it remains "undefined" Thanks for all your answers ! :)

Comment: I've added a check to see if the checkbox is checked as well... check out this JSBin example: http://jsbin.com/imofoh/1/edit

Comment: Your jsbin works fine with Firefox, but I can't even manage to load the page with IE8. Is-it possible that my problem comes from this browser ? And because of some restrictive rights and proxy on the computers of my office, I can't test my site on Firefox / Chrome, the configuration of the proxy only allows me to open my localhost in IE.

Comment: this might be a problem with your MSIE, I just copy-pasted the JSBin example into a local file, opened it in MSIE9 and tried to run it in both - IE9 and IE8 modes... IE9 warns about the JavaScript but otherwise works when you confirm you want to run it... IE8 runs even without any warnings

Comment: I copied your JSBin example into a local file too, and it worked in IE... I really don't see where is the problem...
I did this : `$('input.pack_check').click(function() {
        if (!this.checked) {
   alert("test");
            $(this).nextAll('input:first').val('');
        }
    });`
The "test" alert is showing, but the value of the text is not modified...

Comment: that is quite puzzling, there must be something in your MSIE installed preventing JavaScript to work correctly... if it works for you locally from other browsers, I don't see any different explanation for it really

Comment: Well, when I tried your code from JSBin with IE, it worked great...

I'll do more search, and if I find something, I'll let you know.

Thanks for the time you've taken for me ! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('input.pack_check').change(function () {
        $(this).next(".date-picker").val("");
});
```